# Sum Timestamps from Text Doc in Java

Tags: java, datetime, sum, timestamp, duration

I am interested in tracking trade logs within a video game market. I am already using a program that records a log of all the trades that occur. It produces a text doc that looks like this:

[00:01:30] Bought 1 Abyssal whips (2213157ea)  [00:00:18]

[00:02:10] Bought 1 Abyssal whips (2213157ea)  [00:00:04]

[00:02:11] Sold 1 Abyssal whips (2214442ea)  [00:00:18]

[00:02:49] Sold 1 Abyssal whips (2215775ea)  [00:00:15]

There are 2 timestamps in brackets, the first is when the trade is completed and the second is the duration. I need to sum all the timestamps located at the end of each line.

Some of my researching tells me I should grab each timestamp and save it as a separate string, then convert it to a date or duration or something. I probably need to loop it for each line as well but I don't have a clear process for that.

I'm not asking anyone to make the code for me, that would defeat the learning purpose. But if anyone could point me in the right direction, it would put me on the fast track to getting this done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would:

- use a regular expression to extract the portion of the strings you are interested in
- create a Duration from the string (you could design your own class or use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)) - if you use the jdk class, it has a [`parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) method but you would need to reformat the string first. Alternatively you could create a `LocalTime` from the string with `LocalTime::parse` and use `Duration.between(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, timestamp)`.
- sum all the durations

Answer (score 1):

> I need to sum all the timestamps located at the end of each line.

You can do it by taking the following steps:

1. Read all the lines of the files into a `Stream<String>`.
2. Use the Java regex API to retrieve the duration string located at the end of each line from the stream.
3. Parse each duration string into [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).
4. Collect the resulting `Stream<Duration>` to a `List<Duration>`.
5. Initialize a duration with 0 hours and add all Durations from the list to it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<Duration> list = 
            Files.lines(Paths.get("log.txt")) // Read all lines from the file as a Stream 
                .map(line -> Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[)\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}(?=\\]$)")
                        .matcher(line) // Match the regex in each line
                        .results()
                        .map(MatchResult::group)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining("")) // Join the only string in the stream to a single string 
                ).map(s -> Duration.parse(toIsoDurationString(s))) // Parse the text to Duration
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Initialize a duration with 0 hours and add all Durations from the list to it
        Duration sum = Duration.ofHours(0);
        for (Duration duration : list) {
            sum = sum.plus(duration);
        }

        System.out.println("Total duration: " + sum);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        System.out.println("Total duration: "
                + String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", sum.toHours(), sum.toMinutes() % 60, sum.toSeconds() % 60));
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        System.out.println("Total duration: "
                + String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", sum.toHoursPart(), sum.toMinutesPart(), sum.toSecondsPart()));
        // ##############################################################################
    }

    static String toIsoDurationString(String duration) {
        char[] symbols = "HMS".toCharArray();
        String[] durationParts = duration.split(":");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("PT");
        for (int i = 0; i < durationParts.length; i++) {
            sb.append(durationParts[i]).append(symbols[i]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Total duration: PT55S
Total duration: 00:00:55
Total duration: 00:00:55
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. `(?<=\\[)` specifies [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for `[`
2. `\d{2}` specifies `2` digits.
3. `(?=\\]$)` specifies [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for `]` at the end of the line. The end of the line is specified by `$`.

Test the regex used in the solution at **[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wW6bwC/1)**

**Important links:**

1. **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**
2. **[Lesson: Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)**
3. **[Java Stream API tutorial Part-1](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html)**
4. **[Java Stream API tutorial Part-2](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Try analizing each line with regexp which starts with [date] followed by some text folowed by [duration] and capture the ending part. See classes Pattern and Matcher. Then parse each found duration with DateFormat and summ them all. No details as you asked.